# Proper setup for IIS7.5 machine account for anonymous Web site access

Tags: asp.net, configuration, iis-7

Using IIS 7.5, IIS_IUSRS is supposed to be the account to use. I get '401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials' error. If I add an EVERYONE account with Read, it works. But rather not have Everyone account. Any idea why IIS_IUSRS does not work? It has Read access. Anonymous Access=enabled. Specific User=IUSR

As a side, on the Basic Settings... for the site, Test Settings button says 'ok-on Authenticate' but Authorization 'cannot verify access to path'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IIS 7.5 this has changed from being an IIS_IUSRS account to being a user under the **IIS AppPools** top level windows group

if you create an application pool called

**www.mysite.com**

then the sites default created user account that it runs as becomes

**IIS AppPools\www.mysite.com**

Check the following Microsoft Doc under "Securing Resources" to see more

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/

Answer (score 0):

Under the 'Securing Resources' section listed [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities):

> 1. Open Windows Explorer.
> 2. Select a file or directory.
> 3. Right click the file and select "Properties"
> 4. Select the "Security" tab Click the "Edit" and then "Add" button
> 5. Click the "Locations" button and make sure you select your machine. Enter "**IIS AppPool**\DefaultAppPool" in the "Enter the object names to select:" text box.
> 6. Click the "Check Names" button and click "OK".

Substitute `DefaultAppPool` with the name of the application pool you created/used when adding your site to IIS. This `IIS AppPool` (not IIS AppPools as of iis 7.5.7600 on Windows 7 pro) group is a group of virtual accounts that you will *not* see when performing a normal account search on your local machine or via a directory service.