# Deploying my visual studio web application using IIS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, http, iis, publish

I have publish my website at visual studio . and i try to setup a website by IIS . 
What i have done is :

I click Add New Website in ' Sites ' folder in the IIS and when i browse my physical path and pool , there is always the error saying cannot verify access to path , while my pool authentication passed .

this is my first time publishing a site , i want to host my site on localhost so whenever i type localhost it will be my site without running through visual studio . Can anyone help me with the IIS error on cannot verify acess to path ?

this is the look of my error :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just spent a long time trying to get to grips with this myself, and I believe I can offer an answer that may help anyone else who comes across this question in future. I think the problem stems from the terminology that is used in IIS, and the fact that you are just trying to deploy one website to localhost in order to test it.

In IIS, a 'Website' (i.e. what you are adding if you right-click Sites and then "Add Website...") is not really what you would commonly refer to as a website. It is just a folder on disk, with a URL binding. The Default Web Site, for example, has the folder \inetpub\wwwroot, and the binding "http:*:80:" which means that any http request (port 80) will go to this "Website". Your website that you have published is not what IIS refers to as a "Website".

In IIS, an individual website is called an "Application". A "Website" in IIS can hold a number of Applications, and you can add them by right-clicking the Default Web Site and choose "Add Application...".

In other words, the Default Web Site in IIS can contain many websites. For example:

```
http://localhost/eStellar
http://localhost/otherWebsite
http://localhost/thirdWebsite
```

all of which may be completely unrelated. I would say that the 3 sites above are 3 different websites, but in IIS these are three "Applications" contained within the "Default Web Site".

In IIS, each "Website" must have a unique binding. As you want your website to be accessible from

```
http://localhost/eStellar
```

(which is port 80) you should use the IIS Default Web Site, because it has the binding already to port 80 and you cannot create another "Website" in IIS with that same binding.

So right-click on the Default Web Site, and choose "Add Application...". In the dialog box that appears, the Alias is the name that you want to use in the URL after localhost, so in your case this is "eStellar". The Application Pool can be anything, but just choose the DefaultAppPool for now (the choice of Application Pool is another issue entirely). In the Physical Path, enter the place where you published the website to (i.e. what you have in the Physical Path box in the image in your question).

I also get the same "Cannot verify access to path" warning that you show in your image, but this does not affect my ability to access the page at

```
http://localhost/eStellar
```

It appears to be saying that it "cannot verify" whether you have access, not that it definitely cannot access the site. This warning was a bit of a red herring for me, as it actually has nothing to do with why I could not set up the site with the same method as you state in your question.

Hopefully now you can access your site at localhost.

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps that need to be done on IIS 7

1. Right click your default website
2. Click on add application.
3. a dialogue will appear you need to give alias and folder path to your application here. along with application pool.

and you are good to go.

Regarding your error, give your login user rights, And if you are using connect as provide the user name and password of your machine to see if your test is successful.

Comment: It says invalid application path , which path should i browse to? the project folder where all my page and stuffs is in?

Comment: i am adminstrator , i have the rights , i don't get what u mean by give login user rights or connect using username and password.. where do i do that? sorry

Comment: which iis version are you using?

Comment: IIS version 7.5.7600.16385

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120525/proper-setup-for-iis7-5-machine-account-for-anonymous-web-site-access

Comment: check my edit , i seen your link , i can't understand completely

Comment: your application should work even with this error as well. have you tested your application?